# file does not begin with '%pdf%-'

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, pdf

I am working on Windows forms application using C#, while I am running PDF through my Windows forms application. Earlier, I was using MS SQL Server (its working fine) but now fetching data from XML files and converting files from bytes to PDF file (pdf format). This is my method which is throwing error:

```
public static byte[] GetUnCompressedData(byte[] value)
{
    try
    {
        if (value != null)
            using (var zipInputStream = new ZipInputStream(new MemoryStream(value)))
            {
                while ((zipInputStream.GetNextEntry()) != null)
                {
                    using (var zippedInMemoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                    {

                        var data = new byte[2048];
                        while (true)
                        {
                            var size = zipInputStream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
                            if (size <= 0)
                                break;

                            zippedInMemoryStream.Write(data, 0, size);
                            /// new code added
                            /// 
                            zippedInMemoryStream.Flush();
                        }
                        //zippedInMemoryStream.Close();
                        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
                        GC.Collect();

                        return zippedInMemoryStream.ToArray();
                    }
                }
            }
        return null;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
         throw;
    }
}
```

This is the line of above method where throwing error:

```
using (var zippedInMemoryStream = new MemoryStream())
```

I am getting following error in Windows 8/7:

```
file does not begin with '%pdf%-'
```

While debugging method then I am also getting one more error:

```
Wrong Local header signature: 0x41430A02
```

**Working Environment**: Visual Studio 2013, .Net Framework 4.5, Acrobat PDF Component, XML
**Third Party Control**: Using csharp code to uncompress/compress data using  http://icsharpcode.github.io/SharpZipLib/

I am also providing function to compress data using following method:

```
  public static byte[] GetCompressedData(string fileName, byte[] value)
    {
        try
        {
            // Code for zip file.
            if (value != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName))
                using (var zippedMemoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    // A ZIP stream
                    using (var zipOutputStream = new ZipOutputStream(zippedMemoryStream))
                    {
                        // Highest compression rating 0 - 9.
                        zipOutputStream.SetLevel(9);

                        var entry = new ZipEntry(fileName) { DateTime = DateTime.Now };
                        zipOutputStream.PutNextEntry(entry);

                        zipOutputStream.Write(value, 0, ConvertToInt32(value.Length));

                        zipOutputStream.Finish();
                        zipOutputStream.Close();

                        return zippedMemoryStream.ToArray();
                    }
                }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Try to catch ZipException and IOException to determine what exception do you have (is it I/O or while zipping your file).

Comment: Yes I did it way, throws me error Zip Exception Caught: Wrong Local header signature: 0x44734555

Comment: Probably your file is malformed. Please check it is a valid PDF file and you passes valid data in `byte[] values`.

Comment: Yes, same data using with SQL Server but it is working fine but while migrating SQL Server to XML format and trying to use bytes from XML (it only string format but sql provide different data type) convert into PDF file then giving error.

Comment: Could you please attempt to unzip your `value` using external file unpacker? Then please let us know whether ZIP image was invalid (problem with compression) or only C# unzipping was invalid (problem with decompression).

Comment: Can you share a simple sample xml file from which you extract the bytes to decompress? And your code extracting them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up this issue just convert bytes **FromBase64String** as following.

```
 byte[] _imgdata = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_obj.FileData);
 _imgdata = Convert.FromBase64String(_obj.FileData);
_pic = clsCommon.ByteToImage(_imgdata);
```

Add this method convert into from byte into image also

```
    public static Bitmap ByteToImage(byte[] blob)
    {
        try
        {
            /// Write memory stream
            MemoryStream mStream = new MemoryStream();
            byte[] pData = blob;
            mStream.Write(pData, 0, Convert.ToInt32(pData.Length));
            Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(mStream, false);

            _Height = Convert.ToInt32(bm.Height);
            _Width = Convert.ToInt32(bm.Width);

            mStream.Dispose();
            return bm;
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Two days headache ended up with above two lines.

Comment: I am also having same issue. I am also getting same error popup. But your solution seems confusing. Can you please let me know how you solved ur problem. My issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32260041/asp-net-mvc-generate-pdf-from-byte

Comment: @Ziggler Did tried my answer. I am adding one more method.